# html How can I get multiple instant results from single calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get a dozen results from this single basic calculation? I have two output textboxes in the sample code; how can I get these two fields to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

<head> 
    <title> multiple results calculation </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="style" href="css/main.css"  type"text/css"/>

    <!-- I need multiple results from single calculation! 

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sum()
      {
         var width = document.multiple results.width.value;
         var height = document.multiple results.value;
         var sum = parseInt(width) * parseInt(height) /144; 
         document.getElementById('Calculate').value = sum;

         document.getElementById("results1").readOnly=true;
         document.getElementById("results2").readOnly=true;


         var result1= $1.99;
         var result2= $2.99;

         document.getElementById('Calculate').value = sum * result1;
         document.getElementById('Calculate').value = sum * result2; 

      }
    </script>       
    -->

</head>
    <body>

    <div> 
        <H2> Multiple instant results from single calculation</h2>
        <p>  the goal eventually is to have about a dozen results from this single calculation
    </div>  

        <form name="multiple results">

            <label for="width"> Width: </label>
            <input type="number" <id="width" maxlength="4" size="10" value=""/>

            <label for="height"> Height: </label>
            <input type="number" <id="height" maxlength="4" size="10" value=""/>

            <input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="sum"/>

            <div>

            <label for="result1"> Result1: $ </label>
            <input type="number" id="result1" name="result1"/>

            <label for="result2"> Result2: $ </label>
            <input type="number" id="result2" name="result2"/>      
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify:  Are you saying you want have 12 results that you want to display in 12 different input fields when you run `sum()`?

Comment: Why would one calculation give a dozen (different?) results?

Comment: @DavidThomas - I think he wants 12 different local variables in which each would produce a different result when multiplied by sum and then those values will be put into 12 different inputs.

Comment: @xaisoft your last comment is what what i need, i just can figure it out.the reason is why have a droplist, checkboxes, or radiobuttons when is all from same calculation i figured just all in one shot save time

Comment: When I run it in Firefox with web console I get “ReferenceError: sum is not defined”

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by removing the first document.getElementById('Calculate').value = sum;, changed the remaining getElementById's and input type's to result and result2 also added the missing value="" to input, not necessary but renaming Id's helped me